Is there a way to add a circle background under one word with hight padding, that won't mess up the layout
I want to add a circle layout to one of the texts.
<div className="col-md-4">
 <p className="text-bold-font">
  studio fotograficzne z HISTORIĄ
 </p>
 <p className="text-regular-font">
  <br></br>działamy od{" "}
  <span className="text-bold-font">1955</span> roku
 </p>
</div>

The idea is to add a circle background to the span with 1955 date in it. Problem is when I tried to just add a background with right border-radius to make it a circle, and then simply add padding, this messed up the layout. I want other words to go over this background, and the circle to be responsive and follow the span. I also tried to add negative margins and zIndex to the span and do it this way, but then the line above it wasn't looking good when a line break happened. Is there a way to do it?

In the image is the goal look of it. Couldn't find an exact same problem on here. Thank you for help in advance!

You may play around with inline-grid and transform (Vs position : absolute )
example below , here is a snippet with comments for the css applied:


.text-bold-font {
  display:inline-grid;/* make me inline and a grid too*/
  grid-template-rows:1.2em;/* keep it to one line height */
  height:1.2em;
}
.text-bold-font:before {
  content:'';
  grid-row:2;/* i'm standing and overflowing below */ 
  aspect-ratio:1/1;/* make me a square so i can be a circle */
  border-radius:50%;/* there i am a circle */
  width:110%;/* make a little bigger */
  transform:translatey(calc( -50% - .6em));/* bring me up on top of text */
  background:silver;/* bg */
  mix-blend-mode:multiply;/* show what's behind too  or use z-index */
}
<div className="col-md-4">
 <p className="text-bold-font">
  studio fotograficzne z HISTORIĄ
 </p>
 <p className="text-regular-font">
  <br></br>działamy od{" "}
  <span class="text-bold-font">1955</span> roku
 </p>
</div>

<div className="col-md-4">
 <p className="text-bold-font">
  studio fotograficzne z HISTORIĄ
 </p>
 <p className="text-regular-font">
  <br></br>działamy od{" "}
  <span class="text-bold-font">19555</span> roku
 </p>
</div>
<div className="col-md-4">
 <p className="text-bold-font">
  studio fotograficzne z HISTORIĄ
 </p>
 <p className="text-regular-font">
  <br></br>działamy od{" "}
  <span class="text-bold-font">19 555</span> roku
 </p>
</div>
<div className="col-md-4">
 <p className="text-bold-font">
  studio fotograficzne z HISTORIĄ
 </p>
 <p className="text-regular-font">
  <br></br>działamy od{" "}
  <span class="text-bold-font">195255</span> roku
 </p>
</div>



